# Nativescript - Add border top To Actionbar

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Hello guys Im having an Issue ,
I want to add red border at the top to my action bar
Here is my code bellow -

```
<ActionBar class=" border-top"  title="" loaded="loaded" >
    <NavigationButton ></NavigationButton>
    <ActionBar.actionItems  >
        <ActionItem ios.position="right" >
            <ActionItem.actionView>
                <AbsoluteLayout >
                <Label text="&#xf145;" class="action-item gray" />
                </AbsoluteLayout>
            </ActionItem.actionView>
        </ActionItem>
        <ActionItem ios.position="right" >
            <ActionItem.actionView>
                <AbsoluteLayout  class="{{ selectedPage ==='contacts' ? 'higlight-menu-item':'' }}">
                    <Label text="&#xf0c0;" class="action-item gray" />
                </AbsoluteLayout>
            </ActionItem.actionView>
        </ActionItem>
    </ActionBar.actionItems>
</ActionBar>
```

and in my app.css

```
.border-top {
  border-top-color:#ec295f;
    border-top-width:2;
}
```

This is working fine on Android devices, but on IOS its not showing
It seems there is no out of the box solution for IOS 
I have found Issues here 
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5395

https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2470#issuecomment-233555881

But there I dont know how to write it ??
Im trying few days but no solution could someone help a little??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution in Nativescript so I had to access native methods of IOS and write my own solution.
Here is my solution:

```
var colorModule = require("color");
var red = new colorModule.Color("#ec295f");
const frameModule = require('ui/frame');


if (frameModule.topmost().ios) {
        let controller = frameModule.topmost().ios.controller;
        let navBar = controller.navigationBar;
        let border = new UIView(CGRectMake(0, 1, navBar.frame.size.width, 2));
        border.backgroundColor = UIColor(red.ios);
        border.opaque = true;
        navBar.addSubview(border);
    }
```

Hope it helps someone :)